# Obtaining Invalid S3 URI error when reading from Redshift

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to read data from a Redshift table into a Spark 2.0 dataframe. 
My call looks like this:

```
 df = spark.read \
 .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
 .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://hostname:5439/dbname?user=myuser&password=pwd&ssl=true&sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory") \
 .option("dbtable", "myschema.mytable") \
 .option('forward_spark_s3_credentials',"true") \
 .option("tempdir", "s3a://mybucket/tmp2") \
 .option("region", "us-east-1") \
 .load()
```

This returns ok without errors.
However, when I run

```
df.collect()
```

I obtain the error below:

```
17/02/07 17:37:36 WARN Utils$: An error occurred while trying to read 
the S3 bucket lifecycle configuration
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid S3 URI: hostname does not 
appear to be a valid S3 endpoint: s3://mybucket/tmp2
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3URI.<init>(AmazonS3URI.java:65)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3URI.<init>(AmazonS3URI.java:42)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.Utils$.checkThatBucketHasObjectLifecycleConfiguration(Utils.scala:72)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.buildScan(RedshiftRelation.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$anonfun$11.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$anonfun$11.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:384)
at ...
```

The data is then subsequently returned...

```
Out[2]: [Row(col1=1, col2=u'yyyyy', col3=datetime.date(2015, 1, 6), col4=datetime.date(2017, 1, 6), col5=Decimal('21'), col6=u'ABCDEF',...)]
```

Points to note:

- This error occurs for both spark-submit and pyspark
- The version of
  Spark is 2.1 and the jars directory contains these pertinent files:

  *RedshiftJDBC4-1.2.1.1001.jar*

  *aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar*

  *spark-redshift_2.11-0.5.0.jar*

  *hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar*

I have tried other combinations esp of the aws-java but in such cases, I don't even get the dataframe to return. I get an an error from the spark.read call.

- The tmp2 bucket directory in S3 exists and is written to with a split
  file containing the results from Redshift.
- This is being run under a federated login and there is no need to supply credentials
  explicitly.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: would you mind how did you resolved this? I am facing the same issue. First WARN and then data returned.

Answer (score 1):

Check if bucket and redshift DB are in same aws regions?